# fill and change the content of div with the chosen <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to google it and found some results in SO. However the point in the discussion is not same as mine.

Before anyone can accept my question, I want to make it clear first what I really want to get from here. As follows;

1. **If this** is a good way for me to achieve what I need with what I have now (the codes), what should I modify from there.
2. **If this** is not the good way, 'by what way' should I change and achieve it.

---

**Oke**

---

**The scenario is:**

I have at least five `<li>` menus in a `<ul>`. In each `<li>`, there are some hidden divs so that the `<li>` will only show the title of that `<li>` but not showing up the main content or the hidden divs.

And then, I have a blank div that I want it to automatically be filled by the main content that is being hidden from **the first** `<li>`.

**After that**, if the second `<li>` and so on is clicked, the blank div that has been filled by the main content of the first `<li>` will be changed according to the next chosen or the next clicked `<li>`.

This script that I have been using is here, but it doesnt work.

```
$('#zen-content').html($('#choice').val()); 
     $('#choice').change(function(event) {
         $('#zen-content').html('' + $('#choice').li()+ '');
});
```

And here is my html:

```
    <ul id="choice">
        <li> fisrt choice <div>hidden div that is going to show in blank div</div></li>
        <li> second choice <div>hidden div...</div> </li>
        <li> third choice <div>hidden div...</div </li>
        <li> last choice <div>hidden div...</div </li>
    </ul>   



    <div id="zen-content">blank div</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zen-content').html($('#choice li:first').html()); 
    $('#choice li').click(function(event) {
        $('#zen-content').html( $(this).html());
    }); 
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/48Qp4/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. But you only find the li, not the div. can I modify it with $('#zen-content').html($(this).find('div').html()); ?

Comment: @inandout, yes, that will show only contents of div.

Answer (score 1):

use the Click event instead of change(btw you have a typo).

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/L24KV/)

```
$('#choice li').on("click", function () {
    $('#zen-content').html('' + $(this).html() + '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the div inside the click li element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8TURA/
HTML

```
<ul id="choice">
    <li>
        Option 1
        <div>option 1 hidden div content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Option 2
        <div>option 2 hidden div content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Option 3
        <div>option 3 hidden div content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Option 4
        <div>option 4 hidden div content</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        Option 5
        <div>option 5 hidden div content</div>
    </li>
</ul>    

<div id="zen-content"></div>
```

CSS

```
#choice div
{
    display:none;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#choice li').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#zen-content').html($(this).find('div').html());
    }
);
```

Comment: But I want it automatically is filled by the first <li>