# The slideshow and the zoom function is not working anymore of fetching content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an images slideshow which each images can bee zoomed in the slideshow. And all the codes I used was working fine before I added some change there.

Here is the working code:

```
<div id="leftBigWraper"><!-- Example -->    
        <div id="bigPicture">
            <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
                <p><a href="colour/zoom/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1.jpg"></a></p>
                    <img src="colour/big/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1.jpg" alt="" width="100%"/></div>

            <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">
                <p><a href="colour/zoom/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_2.jpg"></a></p>
                    <img src="colour/big/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_2.jpg" alt="" width="100%"/></div>              
        </div>


        <div id="smallPicture">
            <img src="colour/thumnail/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1.jpg" width="100%">
            <img src="colour/thumnail/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_2.jpg" width="100%">
        </div>

</div><!-- End of Example -->
<!--End of Wraper in the Left Side (Product Images)-->
```

---

---

In the working code, all the content in the `#bigPicture` div is set maually, and the slideshow is run by this script:

```
var $el = $('#leftBigWraper'),

//  SETUP  ////////
F = 600 ,    // Fade Time
P = 5000 ,   // Pause Time
C = 0 ,      // Counter / Start Slide# (0 based)
///////////////////

$sl = $('#bigPicture > div'),
$th = $('#smallPicture > img'),
N = $sl.length,
T = 10000;

$sl.hide().eq(C).show();
$th.eq(C).addClass('on');


// ANIMATION
function anim() { 
   $sl.eq(C%N).stop(1).fadeTo(F,1).siblings().fadeTo(F,0);
   $th.removeClass('on').eq(C%N).addClass('on');
}

// AUTO ANIMATE     
function autoAnim() {   
   T = setTimeout(function() {
   C++;
   anim();     // Animate
   autoAnim(); // Prepare another iteration
  }, P+F);
}

autoAnim();      // Start loop

// HOVER PAUSE
$el.hover(function(e) {
   return e.type==='mouseenter'? clearTimeout( T ) : autoAnim();
});

// HOVER THUMBNAILS
$th.on('mouseenter', function() {
   C = $th.index( this );
   anim();
});
```

---

[**THE WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/HPLEL/)

---

---

---

**However**, when all the contents in the `#bigPicture` div are set by calling it from `hidden` div and with Jquery, the slideshow and the zooming function is not working anymore.

The Jquery that I used to fill the **blank div** from the **hidden div** is here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#bigPicture').html($('#pilihWarna li #bigHidden:first').html());
      $('#smallPicture').html($('#pilihWarna li #smallHidden:first').html());

   $('#pilihWarna li').click(function(event) {
      $('#bigPicture').html($(this).find('#bigHidden').html());
      $('#smallPicture').html($(this).find('#smallHidden').html());
   }); 
});
```

As follows:

---

**First**, I left the div of `#bigPicture` to be blank or without any content in there.

```
<!--Wraper in the Left Side (Product Images)-->     
<div id="leftBigWraper"><!-- Example -->

        <div id="bigPicture"></div>

        <div id="smallPicture"></div>       
</div><!-- End of Example -->
<!--End of Wraper in the Left Side (Product Images)-->
```

---

**Then**, I create some hidden div that will transfer all the contents insede the div to the `#bigPicture` div.

```
    <ul id="pilihWarna" style="">

        <li><img src="colour/thumnail/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1_7.jpg" width="10%">              

            <div id="bigHidden">
                <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">                        
                    <p><a href="colour/zoom/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1.jpg"></a></p>                      
                        <img src="colour/big/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1.jpg"></div>

                <div class="easyzoom easyzoom--overlay">                        
                    <p><a href="colour/zoom/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_2.jpg"></a></p>                      
                        <img src="colour/big/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_2.jpg"></div>
            </div>                      

            <div id="smallHidden">
                <img src="colour/thumnail/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_1.jpg">
                <img src="colour/thumnail/Evan-Picone-Turtleneck-Sweater-Dress__01688224_balired_2.jpg">
            </div>                                  
        </li>
```

---

The `ul` which its id is `#pilihanWarna` has at least 5 `li`, which I used as clickable menus that I have been discussing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702433/fill-and-change-the-content-of-div-with-the-chosen-li)

That's when the slidshow and the zooming images functions are not working anymore.

Comment: I am wondring if this is caused by the conflict of the scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same IDs multiple times, IDs should be unique. Given multiple elements with the same ID:

```
<div id="foo">One</div>
<div id="foo">Two</div>
<div id="foo">Three</div>
```

Searching the DOM for the elements will only ever return the first instance:

```
document.getElementById('foo'); // returns <div id="foo">One</div>
```

Start by removing the duplicated IDs and using a different selector (a class probably, but you could just use an element selector too) and then you might be getting somewhere.

Comment: Do you mean the same ID of the div inside `li` which is `#bigHidden?` I have tried to remove the ID in each DIV but it still doesn't work.

Comment: To be honest your whole setup is not really a smart way of solving the problem. The concept of swapping out the markup and expecting it to work is incorrect, the plugins references to elements and event handlers would all be broken. You really should be basing your solution on the plugin's `.swap()` method.